# Is there any state that satisfies for all $x$, $x$ equals $5$

Tags: first-order-logic

If I have an assertion: for all $x$, $x$ equals $5$
Is there any state that satisfies this assertion?

Does the state $x=5$ satisfy the above?

I believe for every $x$, $x$ cannot be $5$. So no state satisfies this assertion?

Comment: The assertion is true if the universe consists only of the number 5.  A strange and lonely place, but possible.

Comment: What do you mean by state? A statement?

Answer (score 4):

What you are calling a state seems to be what it usually called a model.  It is a set of elements and relationships between them that satisfy a set of axioms.  If you have an axiom $\forall x (x=5)$ the model $\{5\}$ satisfies that axiom.  If you have an axiom (your belief) that $\forall x (x \neq 5)$ any model that does not include $5$ satisfies it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one clarification:
if the model is set of all integers, there is no way the axiom is satisfied, right?

Comment: That is correct, if the model is the set of all integers neither of these two axioms is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you...you have been of great help!!

Comment: An empty model would also seem to qualify.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:  Good point.

Comment: @RossMillikan In first order logic, $5$ is a constant, and thus a term. In a standard semantics for first-order logic, the interpretation function maps _every_ term to an element of the domain.  If $\forall x\,(x \ne 5)$ is a sentence, then $5$ must be mapped to some element of the domain.  Another perspective, since $5$ is a term, from $\forall x(x \ne 5)$ and existential introduction, we may infer $\exists y \forall x (x \ne y)$, which cannot be true. [Free logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/) doesn't make this requirement, though.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Non-empty models typically aren't permitted in first-order logic, as it makes a number of expected inferences fail.

Comment: There's actually a discussion of some of these topics (requiring non-empty domains, interpretations, &c.) in the comments on one of my [past answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/412396/72995), as well as the tail end of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/377682/72995).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a model for first-order logic specifies a non-empty domain of discourse $D$ (or universe) and an interpretation function $\cal I$ that maps each constant symbol to an element of the domain, each relation symbol to a relation on the domain (e.g., a 2-ary relation symbol is mapped to a subset of $D \times D$), and each function symbol to a function on $D$.

If a model satisfies the sentence $\forall x (x = 5)$, then what must be true?  For every element $e$ of the domain, then $(e,\cal I(5)) \in \cal I(=)$, that is, whatever the interpretation of $5$ in the domain is, every other element of the domain must be the same as it (assuming that $=$ is, in fact, mapped to the actual equivalence relation).  Then the domain must be $\{5\}$.

If you let the $\cal I$ map $=$ to something other than the actual equivalence relation on $D$, that is, if you let it be an arbitrary 2-ary relation, you can also come up with some models, but that's not particularly interesting, since you're just saying $\forall x P(x,5)$ for some relation $P$.